# unordered_map of class following pImpl idiom using unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++17, unique-ptr, std-pair, pimpl-idiom

Here is a simplified code: https://godbolt.org/z/EnE76xMrP
The pImpl will contain a mutex member which make the pImpl neither copyable nor movable. But the Foo class has unique_ptr of pImpl as member which make Foo movable but not copyable.

```
class Foo final
{
public:
    Foo();
    ~Foo();
    void DoSomething(const int thread_num);
private:
    int data{};
    struct Impl;
    std::unique_ptr<Impl> m_impl;
};

struct Foo::Impl final
{
    mutable std::mutex m_mutex;
};

Foo::Foo()
    : m_impl(std::make_unique<Impl>()) 
{}

Foo::~Foo() {
    std::cout << "Foo dtor \n";
}
```

For mapping keys to Foo values, I used emplace. But it looks even constructing a pair<int, Foo> is not feasible. Would you please clarify ? Because the compiler message is somewhat cumbersome:
`no matching function for call to 'std::pair<int, Foo>::pair(int, Foo)'`
I tried to use shared_ptr instead of unique_ptr, and it works, but my question is why?

Comment: You probably want to use std::piecewise_construct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this compiles if you modify the class definition to have an explicitly defined move constructor.

working with Pimpl requires all "exposed" constructors and destructors to be declared in the headers, and implemented in the cpp.

```
class Foo final
{
public:
    Foo();
    ~Foo();
    Foo(Foo&&) noexcept;
    Foo& operator=(Foo&&) noexcept;
    void DoSomething(const int thread_num);
private:
    int data{};
    struct Impl;
    std::unique_ptr<Impl> m_impl;
};

// in the cpp
Foo::Foo(): m_impl(std::make_unique<Impl>()) {};
Foo::~Foo() = default;
Foo::Foo(Foo&&) noexcept = default; 
Foo& Foo::operator=(Foo&&) noexcept = default;
```

you also need a move assignment operator `Foo& operator=(Foo&&)` if you ever intend to move assign it.

also note that you should use `std::pair<int, Foo>` not `std::pair<int, Foo&&>` as this rvalue Reference would be dangling, hence the SIGSEGV

---

Edit: the reason you need to explicitly define the move constructor is because `unique_ptr` move constructor will try to invoke `Impl` destructor which is only defined inside the cpp file.

Comment: This is because copy/move constructors/assignments and destructors will delegate these operations to all members (including the unique_ptr member), which in turn will delegate them to its managed `T` instance. In order to do that, it is required to have the full definition (so compiler knows what members `T` implements and the like). Since in the header this is not possible, the default members are just deleted. You have to explicitly implement them (even if just by defaulting them) in the cpp file, where the full definition is available

Comment: @LoPiTaL you are correct, the answer has been updated to reflect the reason.

Comment: The issue is solved when class declaration and implementation are in same file: https://godbolt.org/z/4TEcYfa4h  
But still there is a compilation error when declaration is in header file: `error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'Foo::Impl'`
here is the example: https://godbolt.org/z/z4rsbPMfx

Comment: @omarekik the move operations should be defined in the cpp, only their declaration is in the header, ie: put the `= default` in the cpp, not in the header, as shown in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because you defined explicitly a destructor for `Foo`, the compiler assumes there is something special about your class and does not generate the move constructor by default.  See for example [Move constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor)

> **Implicitly-declared move constructor**
>
> If no user-defined move constructors are provided for a class type, and all of the following is true:
>
> - there are no user-declared copy constructors;
> - there are no user-declared copy assignment operators;
> - there are no user-declared move assignment operators;
> - **there is no user-declared destructor.**
>
> Then the compiler will declare a move constructor as a non-explicit inline public member of its class with the signature `T::T(T&&)`.

If you remove the definition for the constructor your program compiles and runs fine.

```
class Foo final
{
public:
    Foo();
    //~Foo();
    void DoSomething(const int thread_num);
private:
    int data{};
    struct Impl;
    std::unique_ptr<Impl> m_impl;
};
```

As suggested by the other answer, you could also define the move operations as:

```
Foo(Foo&&) = default;
Foo& operator=(Foo&&) = default;
```

(although there should be no concern about header filer vs implementation unit.)